# scheme style guide

Tags: coding-style, lisp, scheme

I've done some Googling for a Scheme style guide, but haven't come up with anything as easily refereceable and concrete as, say, the [Google Style Guide for C++](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml). The best I've found so far is [this guy](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt). Are there Scheme style guides out there that are as good or better?

Comment: What is wrong with the "this guy" guide?  It seems more detailed than the Google one even.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for something more navigable and scan-able than a raw .txt file. The Google style guide is great in this respect, which is why I am able to adhere to it and still feel like it's doing more good than harm to my coding experience.

Comment: It's an `-*- outline -*-` text file, so if you don't find that easy enough to skim, you can pretty easily convert it to HTML or anything else.  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"That guy" is quite good and you should read that.

Answer (score 2):

Google just released their [style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lispguide.xml) for Common Lisp, I think most of the general principles should also apply to scheme. There are also [discussions and comments](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4639490) about this guide on Hacker News.

Answer (score 0):

The Scheme wiki has a [style guide](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style).  It may not be as complete but it gives you the idea.